# Is there a way to simplify my thinking about the N towers of M heights game?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, game-theory

To summarize the game, there are N towers of height M, on each turn the player can reduce a tower to a number that divides its height but doesn't equal its height, and the goal is to make your opponent have no possible moves when its his turn.

For example, if `N=2,M=2` then the first player loses because the only moves he can do are to reduce one of the towers to height 1 after which the only move the other player can do is reduce the other tower to height 1 and now the first player has no moves to do.

I started writing this out, but it's getting too complicated for me to really see a "pattern" on the non-prime `M`s such as `4`. Is there are better way I should be thinking about this?

```
1 --> Lose
1 1 --> Lose
1 1 1 --> Lose
etc. 

2 --> Win
2 2 --> Lose
2 2 2 --> Win
2 2 2 2 --> Lose
etc. 

3 --> Win
3 3 --> Lose
3 3 3 --> Win
3 3 3 3 --> Lose
etc.

4 --> Win
4 4 --> Lose (see tree below)

                   4,4                        1's turn
                  /   \
                 /     \
                /       \
               /         \
              /           \
            2,4           1,4                 2's turn  
           / \  \         /  \
          /   \  \       /    \
         /     \  \     /      \
        1,4   2,2 1,2  1,1     1,2            1's turn         
       /  \    \     \           \
      /    \    \     \           \
     1,1  1,2   1,2    1,1        1,1         2's turn
          /      \
         /        \
        1,1       1,1                         1's turn
```

My way of calculating whether player 1 or 2 will win is like

```
static int Winner(int n, int m)
{
    if(m == 1)
        return 2;
    else if(IsPrime(m))
        return n % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
    else
    {
       // ... ??
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Wow, I just made a wild guess with

```
static int Winner(int n, int m)
{
    if(m == 1)
        return 2;
    else
        return n % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

and it passed all the test cases of the challenge problem. So I "solved" it without understanding why.

Comment: What's the scale of `N` and `M`?

Comment: @amit 1<= N, M <= 10^6. But why does that matter for my question?

Comment: Because for small scale problems you can usually stand less efficient solution - and there is no need to overengineer it. OTOH, sometimes big scale problems are simply infeasible and you will sattle for approximation. The limitation of a problem is critical to understand the tools and your disposal to solve it.

Comment: Are you familiar with winning strategies for [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rule out the towers starting with height 1. We can also rule out the heights starting with prime numbers. If they are all prime numbers, then there's only one possible move for each player. One tower is reduced to height 1 at a time, until they are all 1 so who wins depends on whether `n` is odd.

So take the case where `m` is not 1 and not prime.
The quickest game is to reduce all the heights to 1 which will take `n` moves. If the number of moves left at the end of a move is even then the player that moved won. Here the first player wins if `n` is odd.

So the players are trying to make the remaining moves after their turn even. A player can increase the remaining moves by 1 by reducing a tower to a prime height instead. The other player cannot repeat this on the same tower because there would only be one move left on that tower. The number of times this is possible to do is `n` so whether a player is able to make the number of moves left on their turn even depends on whether `n` is odd.

Comment: That does not solve anything. Why would both players be limited to reducing a tower to a height of 1 or a prime number ?

Comment: @nelxiost They're the only forcing moves. 1 leaves no more moves and a prime leave a single possible move. Any other move just gives control to the other player. If you want to take the last move on a tower then leaving 1 does this. If you don't, then make any move other than leaving a prime, and the other player will leave 1.

Comment: I'd love to play a game with you. Let's say two tower of height 8. I start, which means I should lose. I reduce one of the towers to a height of 4. The only winning move for you is to reduce the other one to the same height of 4, which is not 1 nor a prime. But since you only play "forcing moves" which are "reduce to 1" and "reduce to a prime", I win.  You are trying to reason with a winning strategy for both players ; or at least, that's what I understand from your answer. It doesn't work because the player in a losing position does not have a winning strategy.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to consider is that when you reduce a tower, dividing its height by one of its divisor (1 aside) is like removing one or more of its prime factors. If you represent each tower's height by the list of its prime factors, then the game just becomes a variant of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim). On each turn, a player removes one or more of the numbers in one of these lists, and a player wins when he removes the last one(s).

Example game with 2 towers of height 6 :

```
Tower 1 (height 6) : 2 3  <- First player removes one
Tower 2 (height 6) : 2 3

Tower 1 (height 2) : 2
Tower 2 (height 6) : 2 3  <- Second player removes one

Tower 1 (height 2) : 2    <- First player removes one
Tower 2 (height 2) : 2

Tower 1 (height 1) : 
Tower 2 (height 2) : 2    <- Second player removes one and wins
```

Once you understand that, you just need to know how to win a Nim game with N heaps of M objects. [And Nim has been mathematically solved for any number of initial heaps and objects.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory)

Since, in your game, a player wins by removing the last prime factor, it is similar to the "normal play" of Nim where the player to pick the last object wins. In this case, the winning strategy is to finish every move with a nim-sum of 0, the nim-sum being the exclusive or of the number of objects in each heap. Read the Wikipedia page for more information and examples. When the game's nim-sum is not 0, it is always possible to make a move that makes it 0. It is impossible otherwise. Therefore, starting a game with a 0 nim-sum means that the first player wins, otherwise the second player wins.

In your case, if the number of towers at the start of a game is even, then the nim-sum is 0 because the towers all have the same height, and the first player wins. Otherwise, if the number of towers is odd, then the second player wins. The only exception is for a height of 1 (which would be an empty Nim game), which makes the second player win by default.

That is why your "wild guess" worked.